# How would I store this data in redis properly?

Tags: json, mongodb, redis, schema

## Collection: years

### Entry 1

```
{
  _id: ObjectId("4f2fd2ee4516ed6ceebbe17c"),
  shows: [
    {
      day: 1,
      hasVideos: false,
      month: 1,
      showid: 1252187000,
      venue: "Someplace"
    },
    {
      day: 2,
      hasVideos: false,
      month: 2,
      showid: 1252188010,
      venue: "Philly"
    }
  ],
  year: 1988
}
```

### Entry 2

```
{
  _id: ObjectId("4f2fd2ee4516ed6ceebbe17c"),
  shows: [
    {
      day: 19,
      hasVideos: false,
      month: 1,
      showid: 1252187999,
      venue: "Hunt's"
    },
    {
      day: 21,
      hasVideos: false,
      month: 1,
      showid: 1252188030,
      venue: "Hunt's"
    }
  ],
  year: 1987
}
```

Now, I created a set called `years` in my redis store. This is populated with strings in the form of `year:1988`. I created a hash called `year:1988`. But this is wrong. I want to nest an array of these show hashes.

How can nest a hash two sets deep? Should I just continue the pattern and create a set in the form of `1988:01:01` and `1988:02:02` to store the first entry?

Thanks

Comment: Could you tell us how exactly you want to query the data? It looks like you want to be able to query by year. This could be done with a zset (sorted set).

Comment: As @JonasAdler mentioned, what you want to _do_ with the data is far more important than what the data looks like, and this tends to be true for _most_ NoSQL data stores.

Comment: Yes I would like to query by year.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you only want to be able to query by date (or year) you should use a Sorted Set as lookup.

[Sorted Sets on redis.io](http://redis.io/commands#sorted_set)

What you want to do is use the show's Id or the serialized show as the **member** and the date the show aired, or took place as the **score**.

Note that if you only store the shows Id you need to perform another lookup to get the shows' details.

Now you can perform range queries which seems to be what you want:

[ZRANGEBYSCORE](http://redis.io/commands/zrangebyscore)

[ZREVRANGEBYSCORE](http://redis.io/commands/zrevrangebyscore)

Comment: So, the key on the sorted set could be `shows`. Then I should create hashes called `show:showid`? Thanks

Comment: no hashes at all, you have one sorted set that holds all the shows Ids or the serialized data of the show. If your going with only the show's Id as member you could store the show under its id `showId -> show_data` or if you want to use hashes: `shows -> showId -> show_data`

Comment: serialized data meaning a string of json? Also, how do I create a searchable date string? Should I convert it to epoch time?

Comment: You can serialize data in millions of ways, json is one of them. Yes, you should convert the time to unix time.